# Finding family of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find family of curves for which lenght of the line segment between origin and the point in which line normal to the curve intersects with X axis is equal to $\frac{y^2}x$

The equation should be $yy'+x=\frac{y^2}x$ but I have no idea where did this come from.

Comment: Also sorry if it sounds a bit confusing, English is not my native language, and I've had a pretty hard time trying to translate this.

Comment: Write the equation of the normal to the curve and use Pythagoreas.

Comment: The equation of the normal to the curve is $$y-Y=\frac{-1}{y'(X)}(x-X)$$
where X,Y are coordinates of a point on the curve.

$Y=0$ because we want a point on X axis, and $X=\frac{y}{x^2}$

But I dont really know how to evaluate $y'(X)$, that is $y'(\frac{y}{x^2})$

Comment: Or should I just assume that x=X? Because that way I'll get what the equation I needed to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little picture says more than a long speech !

[image]

The ODE leads to  $y(x)=x\sqrt{c-2*\ln(x)}$ or $y(x)=-x\sqrt{c-2*\ln(x)}$

The curve drawn on the figure is symbolic : it is not supposed to be a true representation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right when picking an arbitrary point $(X,Y)$ on the curve and writing down the line perpendicular to the tangent in that point:
$$y-Y=\frac{-1}{y'(X)}(x-X).$$ Now the assumptions is that $(\frac{Y^2}{X},0)$ lies on this line and plugging this into the eqaution yields
$$-Y=\frac{-1}{y'(X)}(\frac{Y^2}{X}-X)$$ which is equivalent $$Yy'(X)+X=\frac{Y^2}{X}.$$ Since $(X,Y)$ was arbitrary this gives you your differential equation. Now how to solve the differential equation? Note that the equation is equivalent to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{xy}$$ and this is a *homogeneous* differential equation. Put $y=ux$ and use the product rule : $$\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}.$$ This gives you a separable differential equation that can easily be solved. Can you take it from here?

> Solution: $y^2=cx^2-x^2ln(x^2)$, with $c \in \mathbb{R}$